# Having difficulty downgrading my Nexus S 4g

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, downgrade

My Sprint Nexus S 4g is running CyanogenMod 9 (ICS 4.0.4).

I want to use stock 2.3.6 which I got from https://sites.google.com/site/baroqueworksdevandroid/offcail-binary. In recovery mode I get this error:

```
assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "crespo" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "crespo"

Error

Status 7

Installation aborted`
```

Now I realize at this point that this has SOMETHING to do with the variety of cryptic code names for the Nexus S phones as well as a possibility that the current ROM I am using might have the wrong code name embedded in it, making my downgrading difficult.

1) What is the code name for the Sprint Nexus S 4g which is a CDMA phone but not the Verizon codename?

2) Does that link have the proper ROMs for this phone?

3) Other options? I need to flash this back to 2.3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What is the code name for the Sprint Nexus S 4g which is a CDMA
>   phone but not a the Verizon codename?

The `crespo` codename is the GSM variant of the Nexus S (Verizon never carried it). Sprint's NS4G is simply codenamed `crespo4g`.

> 2) Does that link have the proper ROMs for this phone?

No, those are all for the GSM `crespo` version.

> 3) Other options? I need to flash this back to 2.3.6

[Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) covers your options pretty well. In this case, the first heading of the answer will be a good start:

> ## Google Flagship Updates
>
> Google hosts update packages for the flagship Nexus devices at
>   http://android.clients.google.com/packages/. You can't browse that
>   link directly, but web search is your friend here. Search for that
>   link plus the code name of the device and the version you want; for
>   example, searching android.clients.google.com/packages crespo ics
>   results in a lot of pages with this link -- the OTA Ice Cream Sandwich
>   update for the T-Mobile Nexus S.

Searching for [`android.clients.google.com/packages "crespo4g"  gingerbread`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=android.clients.google.com/packages%20%22crespo4g%22%20gingerbread) returns a number of results. One of them is [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1445655), with a collection of links to stock firmwares.

Comment: very helpful, now I get installation aborted on the image I chose. waah. okay I'm on the right track though